# The 15 V valve not driven by an IRF3205

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, transistors, mosfet, mosfet-driver

I am trying to drive a 16 V pressure valve using an IRF3205 MOSFET.

I am using a TMS320F280025C controller to generate PWM signals. The PWM pulses have a frequency of 20 kHz and a voltage of 3.3 V with a 50% duty cycle.

I have connected the PWM output of the controller to the gate of the IRF3205 as shown in the diagram below. Instead of an LED I am using a valve, and instead of 24 V I am using a 16 V supply.

[image]

I can see 3.3 V pulses  on the oscilloscope at the gate of the IRF3205.  I do not get any signal on the oscilloscope at the valve side, and the valve does not operate. The multimeter does not even show any voltage across the valve. What could be the reason?

Comment: Either use a logic-level gate MOSFET or translate the 3.3V to 16V to drive IRF3205.

Comment: So, you left R4 in circuit?

Comment: Driving inductive load with high frequency PWM is not properly.

Answer (score 0):

The IRF3205 has a V<sub>GS(th)</sub> of 2 to 4 V, according to the [datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRF3205-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355def244190a). This threshold voltage is where the MOSFET just starts conducting, in the order of 250 μA (also see *[How important is the gate threshold voltage on a MOSFET?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/531966/how-important-is-the-gate-threshold-voltage-on-a-mosfet/531968#531968)*).

So, the 3.3 V on the gate is not nearly enough to allow the sort of current you need to run; also see the figures on page 3 of the datasheet.

You need a logic-level MOSFET that will work with V<sub>GS</sub> = 3.3 V, or a MOSFET gate driver or voltage level translator.

Comment: Hello, Please suggest transistor

Comment: @SAU If you feel this answers your question, you may want to accept it and/or vote for it; it's how this site works. We don't do product recommendations here, but Google should give you several alternatives.